# Dropdown created via jquery ajax:how to get related items in second dropdown of selected value in first dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I m trying to fill 2nd dropdown but its not filling with filter data but it fetches all states rather only related states according to country selected in first dropdown Please tell me whats wrong in code.Value of id cannot be found so all states name are filled in dropdown .

```
               <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){             

    $("#country").change(function(){            

        //var optionValue = $("select[name='country_select']").val();      
       var id=$("#country").val(); 
        //var dataString = 'id='+ id;          
          //alert("datastring"+dataString); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getstate.php",
            data: {Country_Id:id},
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#ajaxLoader").show(); },
            complete: function(){ $("#ajaxLoader").hide(); },
            success: function(response){

                $("#stateAjax").html(response);
                $("#stateAjax").show();

        }

        });        
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>
<body>
<form method="post">
Select Country:<select name="country_select" id="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php
$cntry = mysql_query("SELECT Country_Id, name FROM country ORDER BY name ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cntry))
{
    $id=$row['Country_Id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
?>
    </select>
 <span id="errmsg" style="display:none">There is no matching option</span>
  <div id="ajaxLoader" style="display:none"><img src="jquery-ajax/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..."></div>
  <div id="stateAjax" style="display:none">
  <select name="state_select" id="state" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Please Select</option></select></select>
  </div>
</form>   
</body>

        getstate.php


    <?php

    echo $_POST['id'];

    include("connection.php");

    $cntry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state where country_id=".$_POST['id']);
    ?>
     State: 
    <select name="state_select" id="state">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cntry))
    {
        $id=$row['State_id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

    }

    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: stop using `mysql_query()`. use PDO or MySQLi !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getstate.php",
                data: {country_id:id},
                ...
```

Edit 1: also

```
var id=$('#country').val();
```

Edit 2:
getstate.php

```
include("connection.php");

$country_Id = intval($_POST['Country_Id']);//if country_Id is integer...if not:$country_Id = $_POST['Country_Id'];
$cntry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state where country_id=".$country_Id);
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but its still not working I tried to echo the value of id echo "country"+$_POST["id"]; but it is returning zero(0) Please help

Comment: I have changed my code Please have a look and please point out error

Comment: Please check my getstate.php code maybe error is there which I cannot figure it out It still fills all states name